# My static files in aws s3 is not loaded in my Django blog

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a small blog with Django. I've deployed it to pythonanywhere but the problem is that all my static files are not loading. When I tried inspecting the the page chrome, it shows that the links are from amazon. Even when I run the collectstatic command, the necessary folders are created in my s3 bucket and the files are copied to the folders.

This is the config in my settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazon.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',}


STATICFILES_DIRS= [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myblog.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

In the console tab of inspection page, I see

```
www.majestylink.com/:9 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:11 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/css/music.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:13 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/css/poem.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:15 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/css/home.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:17 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/css/video.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:196 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:197 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:155 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/img/fb.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:159 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/img/wp.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:163 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/img/ig.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:167 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/img/yb.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
www.majestylink.com/:171 GET https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazon.com/static/img/tt.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Please what am I not doing right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` which means you got the wrong domain name. It's `s3.amazonaws.com` not `s3.amazon.com`. Use:

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

If it still doesn't work, try the region you're using. For example:

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.us-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Here's an example of one of your URLs working:

https://majestylinkbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/tt.png